# repo.grails.org - cert expired

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Can't build my project any more because the repo certificate has expired. I've tried using --offline but it still seems to try to hit the url and fails. Any thoughts on an alternative?

build.gradle...

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}
```

[image]

Comment: A new certificate is in place now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem, a workaround is to use http instead of https in build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }

    }
....
}


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This has been reported here, watch the report for progress info: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11082

You can *temporarily* change https to http, but be sure to revert that change ASAP once the cert issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks Burt! Silly me didn't even think about posting it on github